# Changing the assigned dummy variable classification when using drop_first

Tags: python, linear-regression, dummy-variable, olsmultiplelinearregression

I generated the following dummy variables for the data to be used for a linear regression model.

[image: dummy variables]

```
data = df.copy() #make a copy of our cleaned dataset called data
X = data[['age', 'blood_pressure', 'specific_gravity', 'albumin', 'sugar',
       'pus_cell', 'pus_cell_clumps', 'bacteria', 'blood_glucose_random',
       'blood_urea', 'serum_creatinine', 'sodium', 'potassium', 'hemoglobin',
       'packed_cell_volume', 'white_blood_cell_count', 'red_blood_cell_count',
       'hypertension', 'diabetes_mellitus', 'coronary_artery_disease',
       'appetite', 'pedal_edema', 'anemia','classification'
       ]]
#convert all object/category columns into dummy/indicator variables.
X = pd.get_dummies(data= X, drop_first=True)
X.head()
```

I want the classification column dummy variable to be classification_ckd

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prefix like this `pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['col1', 'col2'])`.
Read further details from this documentation [Pandas-doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)